# Application failed to start after timestamp check failed in monit

Tags: monit

I am having a simple monit control file which contains the following

```
check process fooBar1 with pidfile fooBar1PidFile
   start program = "/etc/init.d/fooBar1 start" with timeout 10 seconds
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/fooBar1 stop"
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then unmonitor

check process fooBar2 with pidfile fooBar2PidFile
   start program = "/etc/init.d/fooBar2 start" with timeout 10 seconds
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/fooBar2 stop"
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then unmonitor

check process fooBar with pidfile fooBarPidFile
   start program = "/etc/init.d/fooBar start" with timeout 10 seconds
   stop program = "/etc/init.d/fooBar stop"
   if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then unmonitor
   if memory usage > 25.0 MB for 4 cycles then alert
   depends on fooBar1
   depends on fooBar2
   depends on checkFile


check file checkFile with path pathToFile
   if timestamp > 4 minute for 8 cycles then restart
```

Here the intention is to restart `fooBar`, `fooBar1` and `fooBar2` applications when the timestamp check for `checkFile` fails. But what actually happens is it tries to restart the `checkFile` instead of `fooBar`.

This check was working fine with monit version 5.5, but not working with 5.18.

This is what I am getting when timestamp fails and after that 8 cycles are elapsed.

```
'checkFile' timestamp for pathToFile failed -- current timestamp is Fri, 08 Dec 2017 12:47:04
'fooBar' failed to start -- could not start required services: 'checkFile'
'fooBar' start action failed
```

Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with a work around,

```
check file checkFile with path pathToFile
    if timestamp > 4 minute for 8 cycles then
    exec "/etc/init.d/fooBar restart"
    repeat every 1 cycles
```

This is restarting application `fooBar` every cycle when timestamp check fails. But just wondering any other better way to do it?